# Find vector equations of a pair of parallel planes, one containing each of the two skew lines.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec p=\pmatrix{1\\1\\0}$, $\vec q=\pmatrix{0\\1\\-1}$, $\vec u=\pmatrix{2\\-3\\1}$, and $\vec v=\pmatrix{0\\6\\-1}$.

Find vector equations of a pair of parallel planes, each containing one of the lines $$\vec x=\vec p + s\vec u$$ and $$\vec x=\vec q + t \vec v$$

I have verified that the pair of lines is skew which was the first task. How do I proceed next? For two planes to be parallel their normal vector should be equal (or colinear). Do I make use of that?

Comment: What is a *skew* line? I know of skew curves, but for lines I don't see…

Comment: Well I was going by the definition in my textbook which corresponds with this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines .

Comment: Ah! I see. A skew line does not exist – only pair of skew lines (it would be better called a skew pair of lines!). I'm used to  speak of  ‘non-coplanar’ lines.

Comment: I agree that it is a bit unclear. I edited the question to reflect your suggestion :). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The planes that you find have to be parallel to the two vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$, so his orthogonal vector is $\vec w=\vec u \times \vec v$.

Answer (score 1):

One plane is given by $\vec x=\vec p+s\vec u+ t\vec v$.  I'm sure you'll find an equation for the second plane.